# regex code to validate SSN OR Tin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a requirement where I need to validate a text box for SSN or Tin, I am able to achieve it if I am doing it individual but I need a regex code which will validate both the condition at a time. The format will be 111-11-1111 or 
11-1111111.anything apart from this should throw error .

Please Help me to resolve it.

Comment: What part of your regex is not working?

Comment: Just use Or condition `regex1 || regex2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `|` (alternative) symbol

```
var ssnOrTinRegex = /^(?:\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{7})$/;
console.log(
    ssnOrTinRegex.test('111-11-1111'),
    ssnOrTinRegex.test('11-1111111')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check if this could help

function validateSSNorTIN(data) {
    var ssn = (^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$|^XXX-XX-XXXX$);
    var tin = (^\d{2}-?\d{7}$|^XX-XXXXXXX$);

        if (ssn.test(data)||tin.test(data)) {
            setDiv(div_id, "");
            return true;
        } else {
            setDiv(div_id, "*Invalid SSN or TIN*");
            return false;

        }
    }
```